# how to insert different multiple arrays in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form something like below:

```
<input name="first_name[]" type="text">
<input name="last_name[]" type="text">
<input name="email[]" type="email">
```

I am using `while` loop to `print`/`echo` number of groups of above form fields it required.

There will be multiple data in it, i'm not understanding how use `insert` query to `insert` data in `mysql` table using `php`.

Comment: Build the query in the loop then execute outside of the loop.

Comment: please explain with example.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to know how many records you are trying to insert. I used `first_name` for this, but you could use any of them. (I am assuming since these are grouped together that you will always have the same number of `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email`.):

```
$count = count($_POST['first_name']);
```

After you know that, you can build an SQL statement that will [insert all of the records in one query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ";
$sql .= implode(', ', array_fill(0, $count, '(?, ?, ?)'));
```

The second line (`implode...`) will create sets of placeholders in the statement for each record you are trying to insert. (The three question marks represent the three columns you are inserting.) For example, if you had two field groups, the statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
```

After you have created the SQL string, you can [create a new PDO connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) and use that connection to [create a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) using your SQL.

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Next you need to [bind your values](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to the prepared statement. There are various different ways to do this. Here is one example:

```
// Create a multidimensional array using each of the fields from your field groups
$columns = array($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['email']);

$index = 1;    // This is the index of the placeholder in the prepared statement
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {  // This will loop as many times as you have field groups
    $row = array_column($columns, $i);
    // using array_column will pull everything from the $i index of each of the sub-arrays
    // e.g. first_name[$i], last_name[$i], email[$i]

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        // bind the value and increment the index
        $statement->bindValue($index, $value);
        $index++;
    }
}
```

After you have bound all the parameters, you can [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the prepared statement:

```
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (you can find comments in the code):

```
if (isset($_POST['yourSubmitButton']) && isset($_POST['first_name'])) {

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql", 'db_username', 'db_password');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO your_table (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ';
    $sql_append = array(); //Here we have the placeholder to be inserted
    $binds = array(); //Here he have the values for the placeholders

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['first_name']); $i++) {
        if (!( isset($_POST['first_name'][$i]) && isset($_POST['last_name'][$i]) && isset($_POST['email'][$i]) )) {
            //We need all the values to be valid
            continue;
        }
        //Add the placeholders and bind values
        $sql_append[] = '(first_name = :first_name'.$i.', last_name = :last_name'.$i.', email = :email'.$i.')';
        $binds[':first_name'.$i] = $_POST['first_name'][$i];
        $binds[':last_name'.$i] = $_POST['last_name'][$i];
        $binds[':email'.$i] = $_POST['email'][$i];
    }
    //Implode and add to the query and then execute
    $sql = $sql.implode(', ', $sql_append).';';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($binds);

}
```

If you have 2 rows `$sql` will have:

```
echo $sql;
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (first_name = :first_name0, last_name = :last_name0, email = :email0), (first_name = :first_name1, last_name = :last_name1, email = :email1);
```